# Burst, Time-Lapse Photo SD-Card File Differences | Import Script | GoPro

Tags: import, command-line-interface, exiftool, gopro

i want to write a custom import script to import my files from the sd-card.

I found the [File Naming Conventions](https://gopro.com/support/articles/hero3-and-hero3-file-naming-convention). Thats helps a lot, but i can't find any difference between Burst Photos and Time-Lapse Photos.
I try to find any difference with [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) but i can't identify a unique value.
It must be possible because the GoPro App do it :D (make different folders during import)

Has anybody a solution or an idea how i can find out more informations about the photos?

Comment: Try running this command (replace FILE with actual full path to file):  
`exiftool -G1 -a -u FILE`  

The `-u` option will output tags which exiftool doesn't know about and you might be able to find a tag which is different.  If you do, bring the result over to the [ExifTool forum](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php) and Phil (the author of exiftool) might be able to add support for it.

Comment: thanks, but i can'f find there any clearly difference :'(